# jquery plugin resizing only background image

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, background, image-resizing

I started using/learning html/css/jquery two days ago to develop my website and its almost ready with only one problem.

I use this awesome jquery plugin by c.bavota to create a background image which will resize to the full width/height of the browser window!

It works great but the problem is that I have other images over the background (cant attach/combine them in one background image) and when I zoom the background resizes but my other images stay the same size and in their location which is not right.

So my first thought is to create a new function that also resizes the other images the same way.

The function I want to edit…

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
            /**
 * jQuery.fullBg
 * Version 1.0
 * Copyright (c) 2010 c.bavota - http://bavotasan.com
 * Dual licensed under MIT and GPL.
 * Date: 02/23/2010
**/
(function($) {
  $.fn.fullBg = function(){
    var bgImg = $(this);  
    
    function resizeImg() {
      var imgwidth = bgImg.width();
      var imgheight = bgImg.height();
   
      var winwidth = $(window).width();
      var winheight = $(window).height();
  
      var widthratio = winwidth / imgwidth;
      var heightratio = winheight / imgheight;
   
      var widthdiff = heightratio * imgwidth;
      var heightdiff = widthratio * imgheight;
  
      if(heightdiff>winheight) {
        bgImg.css({
          width: winwidth+'px',
          height: heightdiff+'px'
        });
      } else {
        bgImg.css({
          width: widthdiff+'px',
          height: winheight+'px'
        });  
      }
    } 
    resizeImg();
    $(window).resize(function() {
      resizeImg();
    }); 
  };
})(jQuery)
         });

$(window).load(function() {
 $("#background").fullBg();
});
```

I have tried to use this function on my non background images but they turn out too large…
My guess is if I replaced the $(window).width(); for example with $(Background).width(); and call the function on $("#imagetoberesized").fullBg(); and the same for .height
It might work. But im lacking the jquery skills to pass the image which is in a

```html
<img src="imagepath/Main2.jpg" alt="" id="background"/>
<div class="Image">
<a href="#" class="tooltip">
<img src="imagepath/imagei.jpg" id="imagetoberesized"/>
  <span>
        <h3>Text</h3>
   </span>
</a>
</div>
```

to the function to test it.
So any thoughts how/if it would work? and/or how to pass my image to the function?
Thanks

Comment: Hi @Cryptic all of your code is on Ask Question content , if not please show more detail ,thanks

Comment: "all of your code is on Ask Question content" what exactly are you asking of me? do you want me to post all my index.html?

Comment: really ?? like "background" <--  I didn't see any ID is called "backgroud", that is way I have a little confuse

Comment: its the background image! sure ill add it to the html snippet.

Comment: I will give you another example ,hopefully it can help you to deal with your problem

Comment: Hi @CrypticKiwi do you have any question for you now

Answer (score 0):

Hi @CrypticKiwi hopefully this code is you want
by the way please let me know if it has any questions

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.fullBg = function(){
        var bgImg = $(this);

        bgImg.addClass('fullBg');

        function resizeImg() {
            var imgwidth = bgImg.width();
            var imgheight = bgImg.height();

            var winwidth = $(window).width();
            var winheight = $(window).height();

            var widthratio = winwidth/imgwidth;
            var heightratio = winheight/imgheight;

            var widthdiff = heightratio*imgwidth;
            var heightdiff = widthratio*imgheight;

            if(heightdiff>winheight) {
                bgImg.css({
                    width: winwidth+'px',
                    height: heightdiff+'px'
                });
            } else {
                bgImg.css({
                    width: widthdiff+'px',
                    height: winheight+'px'
                });     
            }
        } 
        resizeImg();
        $(window).resize(function() {
            resizeImg();
        }); 
    };

    $.fn.fullBg1 = function () {
        var bgImg = $(this);
        alert(bgImg.width())
        bgImg.addClass('fullBg');

        function resizeImg() {
            var imgwidth = bgImg.width();
            var imgheight = bgImg.height();

            var winwidth = $(window).width()/10;
            var winheight = $(window).height()/10;

            var widthratio = winwidth / imgwidth;
            var heightratio = winheight / imgheight;

            var widthdiff = heightratio * imgwidth;
            var heightdiff = widthratio * imgheight;

            if (heightdiff > winheight) {
                bgImg.css({
                    width: winwidth + 'px',
                    height: heightdiff + 'px'
                });
            } else {
                bgImg.css({
                    width: widthdiff + 'px',
                    height: winheight + 'px'
                });
            }
        }
        resizeImg();
        $(window).resize(function () {
            resizeImg();
        });
    };
})(jQuery)

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Full Size Background Image jQuery Plugin - Demo | bavotasan.com</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fullbg.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.fullBg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index:-90;
}
.fullBg1 {
    position: fixed;

    overflow: hidden;
    z-index:10;
}

#maincontent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 50;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 0.9; 
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);
    }

#box {
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0 10px;
    }

h1 { 
    margin-top: 12px;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 44px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: Georgia,serif;
    color: #222;
    }

h2 { 
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: Georgia,serif;
    color: #C52D08;
    }

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #C52D08;
    }

    a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
        }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<img src="images/bg.jpg" alt="" id="background" />
<div id="maincontent">
    <div id="box">
        <h1>Full Size Background Image jQuery Plugin</h1>
        <h2>Demo</h2>
        Just resize this window and you will see the plugin in action. Whenever the window size changes, the background image size changes. AND it always stays in the proper aspect ratio.
        <p><a href="http://bavotasan.com/?p=1748">&laquo; back to tutorial</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
    <img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/af217662e49a4cbda030feae88418cdd.png" id="imagetoberesized" style="width:100px;height:100px;" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#background").fullBg();
    $("#imagetoberesized").fullBg1();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
<script>

</script>
```

Comment: I will give you all codes and reference  if this is you want.

Comment: No willie it’s not what I want, after running this script you posted the background remains fixed and only the images added to the background  zoom in and out. What I want is background and images to resize together ie: what the script I posted does (resizes the background to fit the window (with zoom) and also to resize all other images with it).
I tried to merge the two scripts but it didn’t produce the desired result.
it would be nice if you can tell me how to pass #background to the function I posted so I can experiment…
Thank you tho for trying to help…

Comment: hi i see, sorry i didnt have a PC now but i will try it again for you next monday.

Comment: Hi@CrypticKiwi I have changed my Answer content ,I wish this code can help you , if not please let me know , thanks, Willie