# Resizing Text Element

Tags: html, alignment, center

I am trying to get my text element to be vertically centered in a larger div, which is colored in blue. I specifically defined the height and alignment as follows:

```
vertical-align: top; //middle actually puts it even lower
height: 83px; //the same as the larger area
```

However, I cannot get this to be vertically aligned in the center of the blue box. Any help would be appreciated!

[image: My image]

Comment: Hi hopefully this url can help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34671291/jquery-plugin-resizing-only-background-image/34672076#34672076

Comment: Do the blue div have a `position` rule ?

Comment: The light blue div does not have a position rule, only height, width, color, and font properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the blue `div` position to `relative` then add the following to your test class :

```
.test{
     position:absolute;
     top:calc(50% - 38px); //76/2 = 38 to get the center of your span.
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfrxf0p5/1/)

Comment: Oh, sorry! I meant to ask for vertical alignment within the light blue box. The orange border denotes the area of the text element (as you can see, its height is different than the blue box even though I set the height to be the same).

Comment: Oh ok that was a bit unclear, sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in several ways:

1. center the division:

```css
div.div{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
   Hello world!
 </div>
```

2. Use a p tag to align the text to the center

```css
div.div{
  background-color: #00ff00
}
p.p{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <p class="p">Hello World!</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. I needed to simply add a text-bottom vertical alignment to the image that was a part of the light blue div. Thanks for the answers anyways guys!